# Configure SublimeREPL to import local module

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'd like SublimeREPL to load a local module automatically, so that I can call functions in the module from the REPL without importing them first.  As an example, `util_func.py` contains the following:

```
import datetime
fdate = lambda: datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

So I can type, immediately after opening a new REPL:

```
>>> fdate()
'2017-02-24'
```

Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was very simple.  I just added the following to `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`.  Selecting the menu option defined by this addition will execute the `util_func.py` and drop into a REPL.

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "R",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python",
                     "id": "repl_python",
                     "mnemonic": "P",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "PATH TO utility_func.py"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    }
                ]}
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Remember to replace `PATH TO utility_func.py` in the above with the correct path.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for finding a solution! Mark it as an answer to keep the site in good shape and award yourself 10 points :D